# OpenMP paralellize a for loop

Tags: c, openmp

I want to use OpenMP to improve the process to calculate the arrays K11,  K22, K33. In this code, I calculate the interaction force between 100 particles. The input arrays K11,  K22, K33 are arrays with lengths 100*99 filled with zeros. The array sarray contains the separation between the particles. The function trapzd integrates the function K_i that is defined in a header file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "FuncInteraction.h"

void ForceVel(double *sarray,  double *K11, double *K22, double *K33, int NTrheads) {

double rr, ll;
rr=0;
ll=0;
int pp;
#pragma omp parallel for private(pp,rr,ll) num_threads(NTrheads)

  for (pp = 0; pp <100*99; pp++)
   {

   rr = 50/sarray[pp];
   ll = 5/sarray[pp];

  K11[pp] = 2*trapzd( K1, rr, ll, 0, 12000, 20);
  K22[pp] = 2*trapzd( K2,rr, ll, 0, 10000, 20) ;
  K33[pp] = 2*trapzd( K3,rr, ll, 0, 10000, 20) ;

   }
                                   
}
```

When I execute this code, I observe that runs in a single core independent of the value of the NTrheads. I would expect to be able to do that loop using more than 1 core, considering that the calculation of K11, K22 and K33 takes more than 1 s.

Comment: Are you telling your compiler to enable OpenMP?

Comment: yes, to compile my code I use gcc ForceVel.c  -lm -fopenmp -o  ForceVel

Comment: Maybe your runtime does some strange binding. Make sure to set `OMP_PROC_BIND=true` and maybe `OMP_PLACES=cores`.

Comment: Is this the only `#pragma omp` directive in your whole code?

Comment: My suggestion is the following: 1) try to compile your code on a different computer, if it is fine, you have to fix your compiler (e.g. by reinstalling it) 2) If the problem exists on a different computer, the only possible explanation is that no threads are available when your parallel region is encountered. Check you whole code for any other OpenMP (or thread related) directives/functions or provide us a [mre].

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to run it on another pc